# Pass Gitlab Secrets to docker build in CI

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, docker-build

I'm currently looking for a way to define ENV variables in CI with Gitlab Secrets so I can override defaults values at build time when I need to deploy my containers.

From what I could find, there is no such way if I don't specify the `-e` in the build command. However, this is not very practical for a certain number of arguments.

My current commands are currently looking like this :

```
# In .gitlab-ci
docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/production:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} -f .docker/production/Dockerfile .

# In Dockerfile
ENV MAILER_URL=${MAILER_URL:-"null://localhost"}
```

I know I could just use build args, but I have a good number of settings and I would like to avoid putting them in CI

Comment: I know that this does not answer the question but - are you sure that you need to pass these arguments in build time? maybe it makes more sense to build the image without the secrets and then add them when you run the container? for example - is MAILER_URL really necessary on build time?

Comment: Actually yes, commands are executed at build time and requires it to be specified at build time. MAILER_URL is just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today there is no direct way to read from file during the build process however you can add all of your arguments to a file then use bash to construct the build command.

1. In Dockerfile you can have the following:

```
# In Dockerfile
ARG MAILER_URL http://localhost
ENV MAILER_URL=${MAILER_URL}
```

This means that by default the value of `MAILER_URL` will be `http://localhost` but you can override it during the build by using `--build-arg`

2- Export Gitlab CI variables to file e.g (arguments.txt) in `before_script` or any other section that works better:

```
echo "MAILER_URL=$CI_MAILER_URL" >> arguments.txt
# echo other variables to arguments.txt
```

3- Read `arguments.txt` and save it in a variable then pass it to docker build

```
export BUILD_ARGS=$(for arg in $(cat arguments.txt); do echo "--build-arg $arg ";done | tr -d '\n');

docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/production:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} $BUILD_ARGS -f .docker/production/Dockerfile .
```

For more details you can check [Set build-time variables (--build-arg)
in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) and [ARG usage in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

---

Also you need to consider that variables like `MAILER_URL` or `MAILER_PASSWORD` from a security standpoint you should pass them when you deploy only and also to be able to deploy your image to multiple environment.

You can take a look at [The Twelve Factor App: Config section](https://12factor.net/config):

> Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code;

Comment: But my question is exactly how to remove them from command line and extract them from gitlab ci env

Comment: I'vre tried your example, however, when I'm running build with an arg specified, I receive the error `Unsupported DSN scheme: <not set>`, but printenv do show me the correct env, any idea ?

Comment: what is the value that you are trying to pass so i can check ? maybe there is a problem with parsing with this value

Comment: Yes there was a typo in my config, sorry for this, and thank you for your help !